# Changing output size of MatrixForm

Tags: matrix, output-formatting

I have a matrix with a large amount of numbers in the rows.

```
matrix = Table[i + j, {i, 5}, {j, 30}];
matrix // MatrixForm
```

The problem is that my notebook is required to wrap everything up at paper length. The output matrix created by MatrixForm as a result does not show up complete in the notebook. Large amount of numbers are cut off. I was wondering how I could make the matrix appear completely in my notebook. Whether this is done by scaling the matrix size or changing font?

Answer (score 6):

> Whether this is done by scaling the matrix size or changing font?

One option is to use Style with specific font size of your choosing

```
matrix = Table[i + j, {i, 5}, {j, 30}];
Style[MatrixForm[matrix], 8]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Pane[]`:

```
matrix = Table[i + j, {i, 5}, {j, 30}];
Pane[matrix // MatrixForm, ImageSize -> Full, 
 ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It can also be done with `Magnify` or by giving the `Magnification` option to `Style`. Like so:

[image: window]

This method has the advantage that it works event if the items in the table are not textual.

[image: colors]

For those who feel the code needs to be  posted in copyable form:

```
matrix = Table[i + j, {i, 5}, {j, 30}];

Magnify[matrix // TableForm, .55]

Style[matrix // TableForm, Magnification -> .55]

table = ConstantArray[Unevaluated[RandomColor[]], {2, 30}];

Magnify[table // TableForm, .6]
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are too many numbers they become impossible to read anyway... how about using ArrayPlot?

```
matrix = Table[i + j, {i, 5}, {j, 30}];
ArrayPlot[matrix]
```

[image]